Puppeteer - Disable Chrome Spell Check
I am working on a project that uses screenshot comparison to perform e2e testing. The testing process involves spinning up a browserless/chrome Docker container and then pointing Puppeteer to the browser running in the container.
There are some intermittent issues where Chrome decides that certain words are spelled incorrectly, which results in the red squiggly line popping up and causing the snapshot comparison to fail.
I know that I may be able to set an HTML attribute on a high-level component but I'd like to know if there is any way to disable Chrome's spellcheck at the browser-level when using Puppeteer? As far as I can tell there is not but maybe I'm missing something.
I'll note that I'm aware there may be other workarounds and am also aware that this type of testing may be considered a bad practice but my hands are tied.
